# File not found when trying to read UWP C++

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I'm trying to get a string from text file.
I create my text file by Right click on project name -> Add -> New Item...
 The file Properties is set like this *Excluded from Build -> No*, *Content -> Yes*
And this is the code for reading the file.

```
void MyApp::MainPage::btn_readFile_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^e)
{
    StorageFolder^ storageFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
    create_task(storageFolder->GetFileAsync("sample.txt")).then([](StorageFile^ sampleFile)
    {
        return FileIO::ReadBufferAsync(sampleFile);
    }).then([](Streams::IBuffer^ buffer)
    {
        auto dataReader = DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer);
        String^ bufferText = dataReader->ReadString(buffer->Length);
    });
}
```

I followed  [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files).

This is the error
**Exception thrown at 0x773A1812 in WASAPI_testApp1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x0083E280. HRESULT:0x80070002 指定されたファイルが見つかりません。
WinRT information: 指定されたファイルが見つかりません。
 occurred**
Sorry for the Japanese 指定されたファイルが見つかりません。mean The specified file could not be found.

Comment: Could you add your error message into your question?

Comment: So is `sample.txt` actually stored in `ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder`? Also note that [C++/CX is somewhat deprecated and `C++/WinRT` should be a preferred alternative now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/visual-c-language-reference-c-cx?view=vs-2017)

Comment: @VTT I'm sorry this is new to me. How do you store the file in LocalFolder? I just place it under project root folder (Same as .vcxproj) and Link it by set the Content property to Yes.

Comment: I think marking item as content does nothing in case of C++ projects. So you probably need to copy this file to the desired location as a Post-Build step. Also if this file is supposed to be a part of the project then it will make sense to copy it into application folder (along with executable) instead of application data folder.

Comment: @VTT Thank you! It's now working. I move the file to the Local folder and now I can read the file. So I guess you cannot install the c++ UWP application with additional files from windows store.

Comment: @VTT What about post the answer out and then OP can mark it. It is also helpful to others.

Comment: You *can* add any assets you like to an application package distributed through the Microsoft Store. You just need to make sure that the assets are indeed added to the package. The choice of programming language doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is part of your project, it is *not* in `ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder`, it is in `Package::Current->InstalledLocation`. Update your code to look there (after packaging it with your project) and it should work. Note that this location is read-only though; you can't write to your `InstalledLocation`. If you want to modify the file, you will need to copy it to `LocalFolder` first.